# POI3.9 XSLFTable issue in Linux

Tags: java, linux, apache-poi, powerpoint

I'm using Apache POI 3.9 (Java API to work with MSOffice documents) to generate Power Point slide (PPTX) file. Everything works fine when i execute in Windows machine but not in Linux machine. The table creation using XSLFTable inside a PPT slide is causing the issue. As suggested in other forum i tried including all POI3.9 jars along with ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar (full version - around 14MB). Also i've tried excluding poi-ooxml-schemas.jar among all the jars. Nothing seems working. PPTx is getting generated but when i try to open the file, it says "File has been corrupted". If i comment out "table creation set of code", PPTX file is opening perfectly.

Can somebody throw some highlight on this issue? What is the change i should make in list of jars added?

EDITED: The jars i added are:

commons-codec-1.5.jar, 
commons-logging-1.1.jar,
dom4j-1.6.1.jar,
junit-3.8.1.jar,
log4j-1.2.13.jar,
ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar,
poi-3.9-20121203.jar,
poi-excelant-3.9-20121203.jar,
poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar,
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar,
poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203.jar,
stax-api-1.0.1.jar,
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

With the above list of jars, table creation in PPTX slide is working fine in Windows m/c. I have copied the same set of jars to Linux machine. But am facing the issue in opening the PPT

Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you sure you have the same jars on both machines, and no other ones? i.e. you don't accidentally have older jars on one of them?

Comment: Yes, i verified so many times for the list of jars and made others also to check.

Comment: It's not what Jars you think you have, it's what ones you actually have that matters! [This POI FAQ Entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) has some code you can use to check what's really being used by Java

Comment: If you create the file on both machines, then unzip the two .pptx files and diff the xml, how does the xml differ?

Comment: The .pptx file is basically a zip-file. Can you unzip both and compare the files and see where the difference is?